# Bar plot with gradual color according to the values in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

[Here is the example of the figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kslKN.png)

I have a database of body temperature monitoring per minute in 22 patients. So the duration of monitoring is between 2000 and 20.000 minutes.
What I need - is to create kind of a "temperature map" for my population.

I was thinking, that the barplot in ggplot2 (geom_bar) would be the best, so it can also represent the number of monitored minutes in each patient.

The problem is - how to fill those bars with gradual colors according to temperature?
my database looks like this (with 22 patients and from 2000 to 20000 minutes and corresponding temperature values):

```
Patient   minute  Temp  
4j        589   38.39   
4j        590   38.38   
4j        591   38.35   
4j        592   38.35   
4j        593   38.38

5w        1     36.39   
5w        2     36.72   
5w        3     36.81   
5w        4     37.35
```

This is how i thought i should start a code, creating 22 bars, each corresponding to 1 patient monitoring

```
> T_map<-data
> t<-ggplot(T_map, aes(patient))
> g + geom_bar()
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "bars with gradual colors"? Do you have some example of exactly what you are after?

Comment: Just added the link to the example picture.
39 should be dark red, that becomes gradually red by arriving 38 and yellow by 37

Comment: I can't see a link. Is what you want something like this `t + geom_bar(stat = "identity") +  geom_col(aes(fill = Temp)) `?

Comment: Thank you, but no, it gives me the same figure as this code here`ggplot(T_map, aes(x=patient, y=min, fill=Temp)) + geom_boxplot()`
that looks like (https://ibb.co/k4mV7c2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the `gradient` to go from defined color ranges as follows: (you can replace df with the name of your dataframe)

```r
t<-ggplot(df, aes(Patient, Temp, fill=Temp))
t + geom_bar(stat = "identity") +scale_fill_gradient(low="mistyrose", high="darkred")
```

## Output

[image: sample_output]

Let me know if you need further customization.

Comment: What is the output of `class(df$Temp)`?

Comment: It worked! thank you! Working on code forgot to change the class of Temp variable, thank you again!